# A certain troublesome property of the complex argument function

Tags: complex-numbers

When writing $$\arg(z^n) = n\arg(z) + 2πk$$ and letting $\arg$ denote the principal complex argument of $z$.
Is $k$ generally an integer or is it that $0\lt k\lt n$ or $k=[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{n}{2\pi}\arg(z)]$ as some books suggest?
Obviously, I don't understand any of this and would appreciate if someone explained this tricky situation..
Thanks in advance !

Comment: First things first: there is not *one* universally accepted definition of "principal" argument. For some it will lie in $(-\pi,\pi] $, for others in $[0, 2\pi)$.

Comment: We know that argument represents the angle in the complex plane. For any z , Arg is bounded by $0 \leq arg(z) < 2 \pi$

Comment: I think it simply means $\;\arg z^n\equiv n \arg z \mod 2\pi$, and the value of $k$ is such that $n\arg z +2\pi k$ lies in the interval we've chosen for  the principal argument.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a non-negative integer, then $z^n=z \cdot z \cdot \; \cdots$ is well defined (analytic and entire) on all $\mathbb C$.
If $n$ is a negative integer, then $z^{n}=(1/z)^{|n|}$ and it is meromorphic, with only a pole of order $|n|$ at $z=0$.

In both cases,the argument (apart the $i2\pi$) is also well defined to be $\{n\arg(z)/(2\pi)\}(2\pi)=(n\arg(z))\mod{(2\pi)}$ where the brackets indicate the fractional part. That as much as $\arg(z)$ is defined.

The above if you define $0\le \arg(z) <2\pi$.
If instead, as rightly indicated in a comment, the definition is $-\pi < \arg(z) \le \pi$ (which is that adopted in all major CAS nowadays), in any case you shall reduce $n\arg(z)$ to fall therein.

If $n$ is instead rational, then it comes that you have to choice the *branch*: the example of $z^{1/2}=\pm \sqrt{z}$ is well known and I will not continue further (you can find [a more authoritative explanation here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)).

Comment: I think you want to remove "except for $ z=0 $".

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: well , I put that to keep it valid for $n$ in all $\mathbb Z$. But your comment is accepted in making the statement more precise.

Comment: Right.  But then you can't say that a function is entire if it is not holomorphic on the whole of $\Bbb C $.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: I tried an additional step towards precision (which in complex field is always necessary, you are right! thanks so much). Is that correct now ? or , since you are more expert , could you please amend it correctly or put as your own answer?